# Calculus two series

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi! I really have been struggling to understand series and the telescoping idea. This word problem is particularly challenging for me because Im not sure how to set up the problem, let alone attempt to solve it. If anyone has time to help me solve this problem I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

So, the distance will be $$13+2\cdot13\cdot\frac49+2\cdot13\cdot\frac49\cdot\frac49+\cdots=13+\frac{2\cdot13\cdot\dfrac49}{1-\dfrac49}$$

$$=13+\frac{104}{9-4}$$

Comment: I think the answer is $$13 \left [1+ 2 \frac{4}{9} \frac1{\displaystyle 1-\frac{4}{9}} \right ]$$

Comment: I looked at both answers and tried both of them, but webworks is not accepting 59.8 or 33.8. So I am still not sure what the answer is or how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you put the units? (lab's answer is the same as mine).

Comment: @user124539, I think you are  looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: @RonGordon, thanks for your observation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need telescoping series for this - the height on the $i$-th bounce is the $a_0 * (\frac{4}{9})^i$ where $a_0$ is the initial height, and $\frac{4}{9}$ is the factor for which the height of the previous bounce decayed by. Thus, the total distance is $13 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^\infty 13 (\frac{4}{9})^i$ (the factor of $2$ is because you have to go up and come down by the same height between bounces, and the $i$-th term accounts for the $i$-th bounce while the first 13 accounts for the initial drop height).

You should know that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty r^i = \frac{1}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$ (geometric series). This obviously implies  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty r^i = \frac{r}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$.